# disable kubelogin for azure kubernetes services

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

By following this document https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/blob/master/README.md#user-principal-login-flow-non-interactive,
i had enabled kubelogin auth to azure kubernetes services. It didnt work as expected and now i want to disable kubelogin auth. But even for the new AKS clusters that I create with the option 'Azure AD auth with Kubernetes rbac' enabled, when I get credentials

az aks get-credentials --resource-group centralus-aks-01-rg --name aks-centralus-01

i see below in kube config file. It is still using kubelogin auth.

```
users:
- name: clusterUser_centralus-aks-01-rg_aks-private-centralus-01
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - get-token
      - --environment
      - AzurePublicCloud
      - --server-id
      - 6xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx0
      - --client-id
      - xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx0
      - --tenant-id
      - xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx0
      - --login
      - devicecode
      command: kubelogin
      env: null
      interactiveMode: IfAvailable
      provideClusterInfo: false
```

Can someone let me know how to disable kubelogin and get to regular auth provider on getting the credentials. So when I do Kubectl get nodes, i should get a new browser tab open and i can enter the user and the code. I couldn't find any reference to disable this.

Answer (score 2):

See, https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2728  - kubelogin is becoming mandatory, so you'll need to get used to the process.

Try to run "kubectl config unset clusters" to clear config, then you'll need to get-credentials and you'll be prompted to use your browser on running a kubectl command.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the *old* form of the kubeconfig file by using the format flag.

```
az aks get-credentials --format azure ...
```

However, from aks 1.25 onwards, you will have to use kubelogin. So It's probably good to stick to it.

---

If your issue is the behaviour of the kubelogin plugin, you can adjust the flags you have there in the exec array. You can review https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin to see possible options.